# subsetting a data.frame using a list in R works sometimes but not always?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I am trying to subset a data.frame (file1) in R using the rownames of another data frame (file2). The total numbers of rows in file2 is 166 and if I further subset it it reduces to 50. Now here is the funny part: If I use the rownames of the file2 after subsetting it (50 rows), create a list of 50 characters and then use that list to subset the file1 subsetting of dataframe works fine!

```
file2 <-subset(file2, Compartment=="Feces")
file2=droplevels(file2, reorder=FALSE)
list=rownames(file2)
new=file1[list, ]
```

However if I use the file2 as is (all 166 rows) without subsetting then it does not work!
It reduces the file1 to 166 rows but rows are full of NAs and some rownames (specifically the ones starting with ET and one more) have been lost!

```
list=rownames(file2)
new=file1[list, ]
```

[image]

file1 and 2 available here:
https://filebin.net/zrzax0qt6n1gwszu

Comment: This happens because in your 2nd approach the rownames you're using don't exist in `file1`. When you use rownames like this it has to return something and because it can't find anything it returns NA rows. Check this example:
`list = rownames(mtcars)[c(3,5)];
list2 = c(list, "unknown");
mtcars[list,];
mtcars[list2,]`. To avoid this behaviour you can use something like `mtcars[rownames(mtcars) %in% list2,]` instead.

Comment: damn! you are so right, but the filenames were supposed to be the same! Anyways, thanks for the quick response and thanks for the mtcars!

Answer (score 0):

Just expanding on @AntoniosK's comment, this may happen when in your second file you have some row names that are not present in the first file. For this reason, R generates empty rows.

You can check that not all the rownames of `file2` are present in `file1` with the following command

```
intersect(rownames(file1), rownames(file2))
#   [1] "C1"  "C10" "C11" "C12" "C13" "C14" "C15" "C16" "C17" "C18" "C19" "C2"  "C20" "C21" "C22"
#  [16] "C23" "C24" "C25" "C26" "C27" "C28" "C29" "C3"  "C30" "C32" "C33" "C34" "C35" "C36" "C37"
#  [31] "C38" "C39" "C4"  "C40" "C41" "C42" "C43" "C44" "C45" "C46" "C47" "C48" "C49" "C5"  "C50"
#  [46] "C51" "C52" "C53" "C54" "C55" "C56" "C57" "C58" "C59" "C6"  "C60" "C7"  "C8"  "C9"  "F1" 
#  [61] "F10" "F11" "F12" "F13" "F14" "F15" "F16" "F17" "F18" "F19" "F2"  "F20" "F21" "F22" "F23"
#  [76] "F24" "F25" "F26" "F27" "F28" "F29" "F3"  "F30" "F31" "F32" "F33" "F34" "F35" "F36" "F37"
#  [91] "F38" "F39" "F4"  "F40" "F41" "F42" "F43" "F44" "F45" "F46" "F47" "F48" "F49" "F5"  "F50"
# [106] "F6"  "F7"  "F8"  "F9"
```

which is a vector of length 109, not 166 as the rows of `file2`.

To avoid the problem you are obtaining, you can use the `%in%` operator between row names

```
new <- file1[rownames(file1) %in% rownames(file2), ]
```

which subset `file1` according to `file2`'s rownames. In this case, `new` is a dataframe of indeed 109 rows with no empty/NA entries.